# box 2d checking for multiple collisions simultaneously

Tags: c++, sfml

i am currently working on a 2d endless runner using sfml and box 2d in which my player body comprises of 2 fixtures one for the main body and one sensor for checking if it is grounded . also the game consisits of obstacles on which the player can stand and jump ..what  want to do is to kill the player if the main body fixture touches the obstacle but not the other ground fixture because that happens when the player is standing on the obstacle .. is there a way to implement such a condition or is there any workaround on how to kill the player when he collides with an obstacle ??
all the fixtures have seperate int tags as the user data ex- every obstacle has int tag of 5 and the player ground sensor has the int tag of 4 .

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show more of your code, but I'll give some helpful tips anyways.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, declare an integer named `playerHealth`. Set it to the maximum you want it to be. Then, write an if statement that checks if the character collides with the obstacle. If it does, write `playerHealth--;`. If you want to remove all health, simply write an if staement that does this: `playerHealth = 0;`. How you choose to switch to the game over screen is up to you.

**EDIT:**
To create collision, simply do this:

```
if (playerHealth.intersects(obstacle))
{
    playerHealth = 0; // Game over!
}
```

Comment: thats fine but the problem is in the collision detection ..it is triggered even when the player is standing on top of an obstacle (as the ground box is a sensor ) .. i need to kill the player when for a given obstacle only the main fixture and not the grounding fixture collides with it (both collide when player stands in it ) .. is there a way to check for such a condition ?

Comment: @B0rn2C0de Here, I'll write that in now.

Comment: but that will return true even when the player touches it from the top how to overcome that ? and for collisions i am using he box2d contactlister instead of sfml

Comment: @B0rn2C0de I don't use Box2D, so I don't know its API. However, it should be simple to write an if statement within an if statement. This time, if you can determine the position of the top of the obstacle, write so that when the bottom of the character is at the position of the top of the obstacle, the player can move forward (but not down) without losing health.

Comment: @B0rn2C0de For further reference, read this (http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/graphics-transform.php) and look for bounding boxes.

Comment: i know about this implementation of sfml .. but using the position of the sprites dosent work properly .. hence i am looking for some proper box2d based solution for this

Comment: Then, as a suggestion for the future, you should indicate such in your question and tag box2d. After all, I don't believe anyone could possibly read your mind regarding what you need help with specifically without knowing some important context.